# Start values as results of previous simulation

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is it possible to use the result of a simulation `Sim 1` at time `t` as start value of simulation `Sim 2`? The use of `extend` doesn't work for start values.

Example:

```
model Sim 1
  Real a;
equation
  a=2*time;
end Sim 1;
```

for model `Sim 2`, I need

```
Real b (start=a at time t)
```

to use in several other set of equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to differ between the modeling and the simulation process:

- With the language Modelica you define your models
- With the simulation tool (like Dymola) you perform the simulation.

The keyword `extends` is part of the Modelica language. So it cannot be of any use in this context, as you use it to define models, not to describe how a simulation should be performed.

The solution for your problem must be searched in the simulation tool and Dymola offers a simulator function, which does exactly what you want: `simulateExtendedModel`. It allows to read the final value of a variable and you can initialize parameters and state variables with it. You can use it in a .mos script or within a Modelica function.

So if we rename your models `Sim1` and `Sim2` to `Model1` and `Model2` (because they are really models, not simulations) the function below would do what you want:

```
function sim
  import DymolaCommands.SimulatorAPI.simulateExtendedModel;
protected 
  Boolean ok;
  Real a;
  Real[1] finalValues;
algorithm 
  (ok, finalValues) :=simulateExtendedModel("Model1", 0, 5, finalNames={"a"});
  a :=finalValues[1];
  simulateExtendedModel("Model2", 5, 10, initialNames={"b"}, initialValues={a});
end sim;
```

If you want to set multiple variables, you can use this code:

```
function sim2
  import DymolaCommands.SimulatorAPI.simulateExtendedModel;
protected 
  Boolean ok;
  Real[:] finalValues_sim1;
  String[:] finalNames_sim1 = {"a1", "a2", "a3"};
  String[:] initialNames_sim2 = {"b1", "b2", "b3"};
algorithm 
  (ok, finalValues_sim1) :=simulateExtendedModel("SO.Model1", 0, 5, finalNames=finalNames_sim1);
  simulateExtendedModel("SO.Model2", 5, 10, initialNames=initialNames_sim2, initialValues=finalValues_sim1);
end sim2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and your answer. How can I use this function but for a set of variables?? i.e. I need to put the values of a1, a2, a3 at time t as initial values of b1, b2, b3 in Model2. Thank you

Comment: I have updated the answer. Note that the second return value and many arguments of `simulateExtendedModel` are vectors, which are created with `{ }` in Modelica. `[:]` specifies a vector with an unknown number of elements (which is determined on assignment).